# Is this case suitable for DI?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I am writing a WPF sample app, and in that I want to display list of items in view. View has `MainViewModel` which contains `ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>`. Clearly `ItemViewModel` is so specific that there's nothing to abstract from it.

Question - When I build collection of these items in `MainViewModel`, is it OK to instantiate `ItemViewModel`s manually, or should it be delegated to DI container?

I am familiar with MVVM (and DI too), so point here is not whether to have `ItemViewModel` (I need it). But if DI still applies here, I seek clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

> When I build collection of these items in MainViewModel, is it OK to instantiate ItemViewModels manually, or should it be delegated to DI container?

You could certainly construct the `ItemViewModel` objects "manually" using the `new` operator if that's what you are asking. There is nothing wrong with this approach. Why would you would you bother to use a container to create these if you don't have to?

If an `ItemViewModel` has some dependencies, the `MainViewModel` will also have these dependencies as it is the class that knows how to create `ItemViewModels`.

So you could basically inject the `MainViewModel` with whatever dependencies it and the `ItemViewModel` class have.